# Breaking corps apart? Adding 2 corps?

Tags: civilization-6

I have 2 field canon corps next to each other.

I just received notification I can now make a 3 unit corps.

I can see no way to join them - or break one so I can try and add 1 to another corps. Are either of these things possible?

The word 'corps' isn't in wikipedia at all. thx.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot merge two Corps. To transform a Corps into an Army, you need to add in another single unit just the way you did to form the Corps in the first place.

2 units form a Corps.
3 units form an Army.

Comment: So there's no way to get from 2 corps - to an army. Once 2 units are in a corps you can't separate them? This seems like a bug or an oversight at the very least?

Comment: @niico It's deliberate, and it warns you that you can't reverse it.

Comment: oh does it? thx I missed that.

Comment: definitely doesn't warn me (mac)